# How can I make an overset symbol at the same size and height as \bar except with a different symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, stacking-symbols

Apologies for the cryptic title, but I was not sure how best to phrase the question in one sentence. I am essentially trying the create a vector symbol with `\rightharpoonup` as the top instead of the arrow.

The output to the following code will feature an overset harpoon over x, next to a simple `\bar{x}`. Observe that on the left, the top symbol is significantly higher and bigger than on the right one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\overset{\rightharpoonup}{#1}}

\begin{document}
$$
\vect{x} \quad \bar{x}
$$
\end{document}
```

I would like to create something that looks in every way like the right hand symbol, except using something that looks like `\rightharpoonup` at the top.

If this command sequence already exists in LaTeX, please use that as an answer, because I have searched for and failed to find it so far.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a clear case for `\accentset` from the `accents` package:

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\accentset{\rightharpoonup}{#1}}
\begin{document}
$\vect{x}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no idea how I would have discovered that package without prior knowledge, but this definitely solves the problem!