# text with double arrow

Tags: positioning

Please help me with the anti-circulant square matrix notation. It looks like the vector notation but has a double line arrow. `\xRightarrow` from `mathtools` wouldn't work because the arrow is in the middle of the line.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to recommend the best way to get the double arrow over the `v` when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\xRightarrow` it not meant to be used as a vector margin, but rather as a `\Rightarrow` with comment. I've never seen vectors (or what ever it is) written with a double stemmed arrow. Do you have any examples from literature or articles from e.g. arxiv which uses this notation?

Comment: You might find [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96141/how-can-i-make-an-overset-symbol-at-the-same-size-and-height-as-bar-except-with) useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are several ways to make double arrows over symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}
\makeatletter
\def\Rightarrowfill{$\m@th\mathord= \mkern-6mu
    \cleaders\hbox{$\mkern-2mu\mathord= \mkern-2mu$}\hfill
    \mkern-6mu \mathord\Rightarrow$}
\def\Overrightarrow#1{\vbox{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
    \Rightarrowfill\crcr\noalign{\kern.4pt\nointerlineskip}
    $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\accentset{\Rightarrow}{#1}}
\newcommand{\vectt}[1]{\accentset{\Longrightarrow}{#1}}

\begin{document}
Here is the usual \texttt{vec} command and my suggested \texttt{vect} for
comparison.
\[ \vec{v}\in\mathbb{Z}^{N\times N} \qquad \vect{v}\in\mathbb{Z}^{N\times N}\]

One way to deal with a wide argument is just to put the accent on the $C$.
\[ \vect{C}_\mathit{Mi}\in\mathbb{Z}^{N\times N}\]

Another way is to define \texttt{vectt} with \texttt{Longrightarrow}.
\[ \vectt{C_{\mathit{Mi}}}\in\mathbb{Z}^{N\times N}\]

A third way is to create a new stretchy macro like \texttt{overrightarrow}.
\[ \overrightarrow{C_\mathit{Mi}}\in\mathbb{Z}^{N\times N} \qquad 
   \Overrightarrow{C_\mathit{Mi}}\in\mathbb{Z}^{N\times N}\]
\end{document}
```

Note that `\mathit{Mi}` looks slightly better than `{Mi}` in the subcript.

---

**Original solution**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\accentset{\Rightarrow}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\[ \vec{v}\in\mathbb{Z}^{N\times N}\]
\[ \vect{v}\in\mathbb{Z}^{N\times N}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this, please advise how to make it work for a longer symbol, say, \vect{C_{Mi}}? (the little arrow is currently covering only half of the C character :)..

Comment: @rimrim - I offer you no fewer that **three** ways to do this! See updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a stack?  The use of `\useanchorwidth` in the true condition means that the size of the overset does not affect the underlying math spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsfonts}
\stackMath
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\begin{document}
\[
\stackon[1pt]{v}{\,\scriptscriptstyle\Rightarrow} \in \mathbb{Z}^{N\times N}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]