# Latex vector notation (arrow)

Tags: arrows, vector

[image]

How do I get such a notation for vectors in LaTeX?

Comment: @nlatexg: Try this in your TeX file: **\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\accentset{\rightharpoonup}{#1}}** with the package **accent**

Comment: No it doesn't work. The arrow above AB stays small

Comment: answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96141/how-can-i-make-an-overset-symbol-at-the-same-size-and-height-as-bar-except-with doesn't solve OP problem, she/he actually ask for extensible harpoons, something like as provided by package `harpoon`.

Answer (score 6):

See, if this is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass[preview, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{harpoon}% <---

\begin{document}
$\overrightharp{a}$    $\overrightharp{AB}$  
\end{document}
```

[image]